# AMQP Elixir library issuing an error "undefined function 'Elixir.AMQP.Application':get_channel(chan)"

Tags: rabbitmq, elixir, amqp

I'm trying to call `AMQP.Application:get_channel` on start per https://github.com/pma/amqp but am getting `18:58:38.481 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.980.0> with 0 neighbours crashed with reason: call to undefined function 'Elixir.AMQP.Application':get_channel(mychan)`. Any help on this would be much appreciated. The function that's making the call is as follows:

```
def init(opts) do
    {:ok, chan} = AMQP.Application.get_channel(:mychan)
    setup_queue(opts.id, chan)
    queue_to_consume = @receive_queue <> opts.id
    {:ok, _consumer_tag} = Basic.consume(chan, queue_to_consume, nil, no_ack: true)
    {:ok, %State{chan: chan, id: opts.id}}
  end
```

Comment: Please share your `mix.exs` (`amqp` version in `deps` in particular) _and_ your config. `AMQP.Application` happen to appear in `v2`.

Comment: awesome. bumping it to v2.1 from 1.6 did it. thank you very much!!

Comment: @AlekseiMatiushkin after having bumped the version, I'm now getting `21:32:50.765 [error] CRASH REPORT Process <0.1299.0> with 0 neighbours exited with reason: no such process or port in call to 'Elixir.GenServer':call('Elixir.AMQP.Application.Channel::chan', get_channel, 5000) in 'Elixir.GenServer':call/3 line 1017` . does this sound like I'll need to bump something else? thanks again!

Comment: It sounds like you have not started the AMQP processes (like connection, or whatever configuration do you have.)

Comment: I imagine that I'll need to keep `AMQP.Connection.open("amqp://guest:guest@localhost")` instead of replacing it the way I did in `init`? thank you!